# $\lim\limits_{x\to a} f(x)=L$ then $\lim\limits_{x\to (a+c)} f(x-c)=L$ by using $\epsilon-\delta$ definition.

Tags: epsilon-delta

My attempt:

Since $f$ has a limit at $x=a$. $\forall \epsilon>0$, $\exists \delta_0>0$ such that for all $x\in Dom(f(x))$ $$\delta_0>|x-a|\quad \text{implies}\quad \epsilon>|f(x)-L|$$

Why can't I just put $x=x-c$ because definiton says that it works for all x in domain, and the implication is already working.

Answer (score 1):

You've written out, very nicely, the hypothesis that is assumed:

**Hypothesis:** For all $\epsilon > 0$ there exists $\delta_0 > 0$ such that if $x$ is in the domain of $f$ and if $\delta_0 > |x-a|$ then $\epsilon > |f(x)-L|$.

The key is to also write out the conclusion that you are supposed to prove, *but* to use a different symbol instead of $x$ to avoid a clash of dummy variables.

As written, the conclusion is 
$$\lim_{x \to (a+c)} f(x-c)=L
$$ 
But let's change the dummy variable $x$ to $y$, so that the conclusion becomes 
$$\lim_{y \to (a+c)} f(y-c)=L
$$ 
Now write this out in full using the definition of limits:

**Conclusion:** For all $\epsilon > 0$ there exists $\delta_0 > 0$ such that if $y-c$ is in the domain of $f$ and if $\delta_0 > |y-(a+c)|$ then $\epsilon > |f(y-c) - L|$.

Perhaps I'll stop here, you can probably see a simple variable substitution which makes the conclusion exactly equivalent to the hypothesis.

Comment: Yes $|f(x-c)-L|\le |f(x-c)-f(x)|+\underbrace{|f(x)-L|}_{<\epsilon}$ but what about $|f(x-c)-f(x)|$

Comment: I've added more to my answer.